# How Do I Echo All The Contents Of An Html File?

Tags: php, html, zurb-foundation

I am trying to echo a whole html code. I am using foundation 5 and if I try to make a form variable inside the php code block, there is an error stating that the classes used in foundation 5 are not functionable. As you can see this is not a finished code so I am just looking for answers right now.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>AskmanProducts</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="js/signinvaldator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:10%">
    <div align="center"><h2>Log In To Access This Website</h2></div>
       <br />
       <div class="medium-6 medium-centered large-centered large-6 columns">
        <form data-abide>
          <div class="name-field">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input id="username" type="text" required="" name="user"></input>
          <small class="error" data-error-message="">A username is required.</small>
          </div>
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input id="password" type="password" required="" name="password"></input>
          <small class="error">A Password is required.</small>

          <br />
          <br />         
          <button type="submit" name="loginbtn">Log In</button>
          <a href="signup.php" class="button">Sign Up</a>
          <a href="forgotpass.php" class="button">Forgot Password?</a>
          <br />

      </form>
     </div>
  </div>

  <?php

    if ($_POST['loginbtn']) {
      $user = $_POST['user'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
    }
    else
      echo 

  ?>

  <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).foundation();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error. You need to use brackets `else {}` when using `if/else`

Comment: No, this method has always worked for me. else always works without brackets for me :/

Comment: Well I guess its not strictly required since it's the last statement in the PHP tag, but I would argue that it is proper style since your code will break if you or someone else adds any code after the else.

Comment: Ah I see. I will start using correct syntax now xP

Comment: You can use if one-liners like `if (foo) foo->bar();` but don't mix brackets and one-liners in a `if/else/elseif` its just bad style and causes errors.

Comment: What is the question? How to `echo` which file? The HTML in the file you showed? It will be shown on screen as far as anyone can tell.

Comment: Yes it would be shown on the screen but how would I make it show/clear the form when the if statements has been done and the else is required?

Answer (score 0):

Rename your html file as php. Example: index.html -> index.php

Comment: Yes the file is named login.php

Comment: so what are you getting currently? the output, take a screenshot or something

Comment: as suggested above, You have a syntax error. You need to use brackets else {} when using if/else.

Comment: Not actually a syntax error (yet) but definitely bad style.